# How to remove labels at the ends of the axes?

Tags: pgfplots

How to remove labels -1,4 on x axis ?
How to remove labels -4,4 on y axis ?

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{pgfplots}


  \usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,bending]
  \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,shapes}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

  \begin{axis}[
   restrict x to domain=-1:4, xmax=4, xmin=-1,
   restrict y to domain=-4:4, ymax=4, ymin=-4,
   x=2cm,
   y=2cm,
   axis x line = middle,
   axis y line = middle,
   major tick style=black,
   axis line style =ultra thick,
   major grid style=darkgray,
   minor y tick num={3},
   minor x tick num={3},
   grid=both,
   y tick label style= {/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
   xtick={-1,0,...,4},
   ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
   samples=5000,
   >=stealth,
   ]

    \node[left] at (axis cs:0,3.8) {$y$};
    \node[below] at (axis cs:3.8,0){$x$};
    \node[below left] at (axis cs:-0.1,-0.05) {$0$};
    \end{axis}

    \end{tikzpicture}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can change the values of `xtick` and `ytick` to be `{0,...,3}` and `{-3,...,3}` respectively; is that what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ArunDebray That will also remove the grid.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: whoa, not when I tried it. Time to update my version of TikZ, I suppose. Thanks for the heads-up.

Comment: @ArunDebray I should correct myself: It removes the major grid lines, i.e. the outer frame. The minor grid is kept.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.: ah, thanks. That's consistent with what I got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possibility is

```
    xtick={-1,0,...,4},
    xticklabel={
      \ifdim\tick pt=-1pt
        \else \ifdim\tick pt=4pt
          \else \axisdefaultticklabel
        \fi\fi},
    ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
    yticklabel={
      \ifdim\tick pt=-4pt
        \else \ifdim\tick pt=4pt
          \else \axisdefaultticklabel
      \fi\fi},
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary[arrows.meta,bending]
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,positioning,shapes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    restrict x to domain=-1:4, xmax=4, xmin=-1,
    restrict y to domain=-4:4, ymax=4, ymin=-4,
    x=2cm,
    y=2cm,
    axis x line = middle,
    axis y line = middle,
    major tick style=black,
    axis line style =ultra thick,
    major grid style=darkgray,
    minor y tick num={3},
    minor x tick num={3},
    grid=both,
    y tick label style= {/pgf/number format/1000 sep={}},
    xtick={-1,0,...,4},
    xticklabel={
      \ifdim\tick pt=-1pt
        \else \ifdim\tick pt=4pt
          \else \axisdefaultticklabel
        \fi\fi},
    ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
    yticklabel={
      \ifdim\tick pt=-4pt
        \else \ifdim\tick pt=4pt
          \else \axisdefaultticklabel
      \fi\fi},
    samples=5000,
    >=stealth,
  ]
  \node[left] at (axis cs:0,3.8) {$y$};
  \node[below] at (axis cs:3.8,0){$x$};
  \node[below left] at (axis cs:-0.1,-0.05) {$0$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You could also use

```
xticklabel={
  \ifdim\tick pt<-0.5pt
    \else \ifdim\tick pt>3.5pt
      \else \axisdefaultticklabel
    \fi\fi}
```

---

Another possibility is removing all tick labels and using extra ticks to set the required tick labels:

```
xtick={-1,0,...,4},
xticklabel=\empty,
extra x ticks={1,...,3},
extra x tick label={\axisdefaultticklabel},
extra x tick style={grid=none,tickwidth=0pt},
ytick={-4,-3,...,4},
yticklabel=\empty,
extra y ticks={-3,...,3},
extra y tick label={\ifdim\tick pt=0pt\else\axisdefaultticklabel\fi},
extra y tick style={grid=none,tickwidth=0pt},
```

The result is the same as above.

Comment: A bit less work: set the first and last label as empty, with `yticklabels={,-3,-2,...,3,},xticklabels={,0,1,...,3,}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Then the tick labels will use the text font instead the math font. AFAIK `\axisdefaultticklabel` is defined as `$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}$`.

Comment: Ah, right. Didn't think about that, sorry. Then one would have to  specify each ticklabel individually, with math mode, which is tedious.

Comment: @esdd Thank you for this solution I will try to understand.